# Firebase limit child nodes extension with wildcard?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am using the [limit child nodes extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/rtdb-limit-child-nodes) to limit a node to 3 children with a structure like this successfully:

```
{
  "-LqRtMWFDSO3QRJDYA39" : {
    "r" : 0.84,
    "s" : "Mango"
  },
  "-LshaeOZsIRC80q_n4Kl" : {
    "r" : 0.49,
    "s" : "Strawberry"
  },
  "-Ltf2gql89DkVm--xLr3" : {
    "r" : 0.44,
    "s" : "Cheese"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use the extension with a structure like so:

```
{
  "34DAvOOUO7N7vp28NtkdAAZp5vD3" : {
    "-Lshag6VI55LMps7Fe0G" : {
      "post" : true,
      "t" : "Brando"
    }
  },
  "35DDKxWrc8c1yERPf2QAYvRPAUb2" : {
    "-LocHP4oF6NzmS67yW8r" : {
      "post" : true,
      "t" : "Abby"
    },
    "-LscHPsdF6NzmE47sdD3r" : {
      "post" : true,
      "t" : "Abby "
    }
  }
}
```

I need to limit user's notifications to 15 nodes only, but without knowing the second child when specifying the path I cannot do this without something similar to a cloud function wildcard parameter.

I appreciate the help, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Since this extension is, in effect, [just a cloud function](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/rtdb-limit-child-nodes/functions/lib/index.js), you can actually use the wildcard format in the `NODE_PATH` parameter (really, just an environment variable that the cloud function is configured with, as well as its trigger configuration).

Lets say all these items are in a top level node, 'notifications'.

Then you could set the parameter to be:

`notifications/{topId}`

Which would create the extension's function as a RTDB `onCreate` method triggering at:

`notifications/{topId}/{messageid}`

And thus clean up the set of notifications 2 levels deep.